# How to return the Json data from Sqlite using JQuery/Phone Gap Plug in

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, cordova

I'm new to phonegap.

What I need to do is return the result set in Json format from this. I'm calling this function like this:

```
var response=getSqlResultSet();
```

And how can I stop my code until I get the **response** from the `getSqlResultSet()`

Please suggest how to do this.

```
function getSqlResultSet() {
    if (!db) {
        db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
    }
    db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB); 
} 

function queryDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}

function querySuccess(tx, results) {}
```

Comment: Where do you need to return the JSON to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is Asynchronous. You don't "stop your code". Instead, you put something in your querySuccess function to carry on with whatever needs to be done.

```
function getSqlResultSet() {
    if (!db) {
        db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
    }
    db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB); 
} 

function queryDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}

function querySuccess(tx, results) {
     // Whatever you would have put after
     // var response=getSqlResultSet();
     // Put here instead
}
```

If you are using jQuery, you might find it easier to wrap in a Deferred object:

```
function getSqlResultSet() {
    var dfr = new $.Deferred();
    if (!db) {
        db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
    }
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], dfr.resolve, dfr.fail);
    }, dfr.fail); 

    return dfr.promise();
} 

getSqlResultSet().then(function (response) {
    // Your code here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For PhoneGap Beginners, this links will be helpful :

[simple offline data synchronization phonegap / sqlite](http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/05/simple-offline-data-synchronization-for-mobile-web-and-phonegap-applications/)

[sample application with jquery mobile and phonegap](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/10/sample-application-with-jquery-mobile-and-phonegap/)